# "Unknown engine type outputformat"

Tags: drush, updating

I did a Drupal 7 update using `drush up` and received the following message, repeated numerous times:

> Unknown engine type outputformat

Since that update, Drush does not work, but rather returns the same message.

How can I fix this problem?

I have Drupal 7.52 and Drush 5.9.

Comment: Drush 5.9 was released over three years ago and is unsupported by its maintainers.

Answer (score 3):

You can install drush to latest version or specified version.
I prefer drush 7, you can make this, first uninstall the current version of drush of your server.

i use debian, then i install with

```
sudo apt-get install drush
```

and you need remove

```
sudo apt-get remove drush
```

and later install again with composer

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

sudo git clone https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git /usr/local/src/drush
cd /usr/local/src/drush
sudo git checkout 7.0.0  #or whatever version you want.
sudo ln -s /usr/local/src/drush/drush /usr/bin/drush
sudo composer install
drush --version
```

and ready to use drush version 7

Answer (score 2):

Drush 5.9 is very out of date (the current stable version is 8.1.7) and if you updated Drupal several versions very likely broke because of a change long-since accounted for in new versions. There was an [issue with similar symptoms](https://www.drupal.org/node/1912752#comment-7046924) reported in 2013 that was resolvable by clearing drush's cache (`drush cc drush`), but the real fix is move to a newer version of drush.

There are several upgrade paths depending on your setup, and how drush was installed the first time.  For options see [How to Upgrade Drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/901828) on Drupal.org and [the official drush install directions](http://www.drush.org/en/master/install/).

Comment: Acrosman, Thanks! All of my other sites are working fine with the old 5.9, but I guess its time to clean'em up and give them the latest drush ... can't live without it.  Your SOLUTION worked! Thanks! [now look over your shoulder ... I was brought up in Florence many moons ago, and lived all over the world since then. Best - Carl

Answer (score 1):

drush 5.x and below fails with multiple **`Unknown engine type outputformat`** error messages when the **Missing Message Fixer** module is active. This module was developed specifically to deal with a problem that appeared when upgrading to Drupal 7.50. It's mentioned in the [module's homepage](https://www.drupal.org/project/module_missing_message_fixer):

> If you are stuck on an old version of Drush (5.x and below). If this
>   module is enabled and you try to run any drush commands, you may get:
>   Unknown engine type outputformat. I would recommend updating your
>   drush or using the GUI version of this module and disabling the module

To me, disabling the module is the solution. Some people get `drush` as a package of LTS Linux distros such as Debian 7 (ships `drush 5.4`), Debian 8 or Ubuntu 14.04 (ship `drush 5.10`), and forcing them to upgrade to the newest is inconsistent with the concept of LTS releases, where every package must be maintained typically for 5 years.

Comment: I did fix Module Missing Message Fixer so it no longer outputs this Unknown engine type outputformat

Comment: Thank you Daniel.  This fixed the issue for me.  I am still seeing "Unknown engine type outputformat" in my terminal.  However, Drush is now able to run and install updates before it outputs "Unknown engine type outputformat".